# Rails 6 + Webpacker add and use yaml-loader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger-ui, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I'm trying to load a YAML file from one of the packs in my project, currently is this:

```
import SwaggerUI from 'swagger-ui';

const spec = require('./swagger-config.yaml');

const ui = SwaggerUI({
  spec,
  dom_id: '#swagger',
});
```

This is to initialize swagger-ui, and I have no problems calling `SwaggerUI` with the given `dom_id`, but when I try to add the spec file, to render something (which is the functionality) I receive this:

```
                       ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/swagger-config.yaml 7:7
XX:53:17 webpacker.1 | Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:7)
XX:53:17 webpacker.1 | You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

If I add the `yaml-loader` to the project:

```
// package.json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "yaml-loader": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}

// config/webpack/environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const yamlLoader = {
  test: /\.yaml$/,
  use: 'yaml-loader'
}

environment.loaders.append('yaml', yamlLoader)

module.exports = environment
```

then I get this message:

```
xx:55:35 webpacker.1 | ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/swagger-config.yaml 1:10
xx:55:35 webpacker.1 | Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:10)
xx:55:35 webpacker.1 | File was processed with these loaders:
xx:55:35 webpacker.1 |  * ./node_modules/yaml-loader/index.js
xx:55:35 webpacker.1 | You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

Is there something specific to do related to Rails in order to load such a YAML file within a pack?

Comment: Shouldn't the file extension be `.yml` instead of ".yaml"? Besides,  look at the first line at column position 10 for the source of the problem?

Comment: If I try renaming the file extension I get the same error (updating the regex as well).

Comment: The strange thing is it says _You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders..._ and it shows the YAML file but as JSON.

Comment: i see that you have solved it. congratulations!

Comment: Yes @BKSpurgeon, thanks a lot for the help. I just needed to keep reading, this webpack/er thing is a complete new world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the [README](https://github.com/eemeli/yaml-loader/blob/master/README.md) from the repo:

> ... For Webpack v4, you'll need to set the rule to have type: "json"

with the `config/webpack/environment.js` file looking like:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.loaders.append(
  'yaml', 
  { test: /\.ya?ml$/,  use: 'yaml-loader', type: 'json' }
)

module.exports = environment
```